# Vector of Vector of object

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a little problem using vector of vector.
I have a `std::vector<AObject*> _word` in my class, I build my word :

```
AObject *object = new Letters();
_word.push_back(object);
```

Later I use :

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _word.size() ; ++i)  
    _word[i]->draw();
```

**^ THIS WORKS BUT I NEED ANOTHER IMPLEMENTATION**

But I need to use it this way :

In my class : `std::vector<std::vector<AObject*> > _words;`

```
AObject *obj = new Letters();
_word.push_back(obj);
_words.push_back(_word);
```

But I get a memory corruption ..

So I cannot use my vector of vector this way :

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _words.size() ; ++i)  
      _words[0][i]->draw();
```

Thank you !

**EDIT**

I tried this :

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < _words.size() ; ++i)
{
  for (size_t j = 0 ; j < _word.size() ; ++j)  
        _words[i][j]->draw();
}
```

Comment: on the last for loop, you're referencing `_world.size( )`, which describes the size of the *first* dimension, but you're using it as the index for the second dimension. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you sure `new Letters()` does what you intend?

Comment: So I should use _world[0].size() ?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Yes it does beceause it works with the simple vector, when I draw my word I have the letters on the screen

Comment: _`AObject *obj = new Letters();`_ **DON'T** you manage memory using `new`/`delete` yourself! Use containers or [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: I can't use smart pointers for that project.

Comment: Then write your own, a minimal unique_ptr is a dozen of lines, and it saves life.

Comment: Maybe, but here I don't see my mistake, I'm sure Letters works, and return my what I want because I use it before and it works just fine.

Comment: @NicolasCharvoz  `for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _words.size() ; ++i)   _words[0][i]->draw();`  Do you understand your mistake here?  If not, it was explained earlier in the comment.  If you do, did you correct it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No I don't see the mistake ..

Comment: @NicolasCharvoz You have a vector inside of a vector.   Which vector does the call to `size` that you are making in the loop belong to?  Is it the inner vector or the outer vector?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The outer vector, and the inner vector too, maybe two loops ? I'm lost haha

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie See my edit, I need to apply the draw method to each object of the vector . So maybe too loops ?

Comment: @NicolasCharvoz I explained in detail how the loop operates in my answer.  If you are confused, just "unroll" the loop to see what each iteration is accessing, just as the answer I gave is doing.  Then you will see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a vector nested inside of a vector.  Note the term *nested*.  That implies that you need a nested loop of some kind to access the inner-most vector.

Let's have a simple example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<AObject*>> vect;
//...
std::vector<AObject*> inner = {new AObject, new AObject, new AObject};
//...
vect.push_back(inner);
vect.push_back(inner);
vect.push_back(inner);
vect.push_back(inner);
```

So `vect` has 4 items in it, all of these items are `std::vector<AObject*>` where each one has 3 items.

Now when we do this:

```
vect.size()
```

the return value is 4 since this is the number of items in the "outer" vector.

Now, if we write a loop as you have done:

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < vect.size() ; ++i)  
    vect[0][i]->draw();
```

You are accessing in the loop (if we unroll it):

```
vect[0][0]->draw();  // good
vect[0][1]->draw();  // good
vect[0][2]->draw();  // good
vect[0][3]->draw();  // <-- error
```

The problem is that there is no `vect[0][3]`.  The inner vector has only 3 items in it, not 4 items.  You are accessing memory that's out of bounds.

So your indices are not correct.  What you wanted to do was this:

```
vect[0][0]->draw();  // good
vect[0][1]->draw();  // good
vect[0][2]->draw();  // good

vect[1][0]->draw();  // good
vect[1][1]->draw();  // good
vect[1][2]->draw();  // good

vect[2][0]->draw();  // good
vect[2][1]->draw();  // good
vect[2][2]->draw();  // good

vect[3][0]->draw();  // good
vect[3][1]->draw();  // good
vect[3][2]->draw();  // good
```

So the loop should have been this:

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < vect.size() ; ++i)  
{
   size_t innerSize = vect[i].size(); 
   for (size_t j = 0; j < innerSize; ++j )
      vect[i][j]->draw();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the indices incorrectly in the block below:

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _words.size() ; ++i)  
      _words[0][i]->draw();
```

it should be:

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _words.size() ; ++i)  
      _words[i][0]->draw();
//           ^^^^ reverse i and 0
```